# How to run two methods returning a Task value asynchronously (/simultaneously/in parallel)?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two methods that need to run in parallel, one method increments i, the other, when I press i on the keyboard, displays the current value:

```
static Task Method(ref int i, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (i < 2100000000)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

static Task Info(ref int i, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

            if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.I)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I tried to run them in Main, but they run synchronously:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    Task task1 = Method(ref i, cts.Token);
    Task task2 = Info(ref i, cts.Token);

    await task1;
    cts.Cancel();

    Console.WriteLine("Готово");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Please tell me what I did wrong, and how can I run these methods in parallel?

Comment: Please edit your question and add details about [what you found when you researched this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and why none of those solutions work for you (with information about what problem or error you received in your attempts)

Answer (score 1):

**Your methods run synchronously because they aren't asynchronous.**

An asynchronous method is a method that *runs a task* that does the job in the background. Your methods don't run a task — they do the job *synchronously* and then return a completed task.

To fix the issue, you need to remove `return Task.CompletedTask` and wrap all the contents of your methods into

```cs
return Task.Run(() => {
  // contents of the method; you don't need to check for cancellation
  // Task.Run() will do it for you
}, cancellationToken);
```

*UPDATE:* the methods are not thread-safe. If they're just a part of your code, consider using one of the many synchronization mechanisms supported by .NET.

Comment: Question: the methods run synchronously and then return a completed task, so they never return control to the caller before they run through their entire body. Would it work better if we added an `await Task.Yield;` line to the top of both methods?

Comment: @Orion No, it won't. `await Task.Yield();` will *return control to the caller* (`Main()`) of the method while going on with executing the rest of the method in a separate task. In the caller, there's a line `cts.Cancel();` after awaiting `task1`, which will cancel both methods just after they started.

Comment: SNBS, wouldn't the line `await task1;` cause it to wait until `task1` finishes its code completely? So at least `task1` will finish, and then `cts.Cancel();` will cancel `task2` if it didn't manage to finish while we were awaiting `task1`.

Comment: SNBS, what if we added `await Task.Yield();` to the top of both methods, and then used `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);` in the main method? Would it cause both methods to execute their code "in parallel", yielding a similar effect to wrapping tasks in a `Task.Run`?

Comment: @Orion No, that's what `Task.Yield()` is created for. It will complete the method (so that the control moves on in the caller) while still executing it in the background. It doesn't matter what do you use for awaiting — whether it's the `await` keyword or `Task.WhenAll()`.